# ChannelRead event does not fire in DotNetty's ServerHandler

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I am experimenting [DotNetty](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty) to use it in an enterprise application.

In my basic examole when I use DotNetty's API in CLIENT to call the server, everything is fine but when I use pure C# TcpClient, only ChannelReadComplete fires and not ChannelRead in ServerHandler.

**ServerHanndler:**

```
public class EchoServerHandler : ChannelHandlerAdapter
{
    public override void ChannelRead(IChannelHandlerContext context, object message)
{
    var buffer = message as IByteBuffer;
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received from client: " + buffer.ToString(Encoding.UTF8));
    }
    context.WriteAsync(message);
}

public override void ChannelReadComplete(IChannelHandlerContext context) => context.Flush();

public override void ExceptionCaught(IChannelHandlerContext context, Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + exception);
    context.CloseAsync();
  }
 }
}
```

**Client:**

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8583);

var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world");
Stream stm = client.GetStream();

stm.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

byte[] readBytes = new byte[100];
stm.Read(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length);
stm.Close();
client.Close();
```

Any idea?

Comment: You cannot use 127.0.0.1 with connect method which is the Loopback address.  You must use a real IP address.  The server TCPListener uses loopback address to listen but in Net library connecting to 127.0.0.1 will cause an exception.

Comment: @jdweng Well, I am not a TCP/IP expert but the same configuration works for DotNetty Client project. Anyway, I changed the IP to the actual one and made no defference. Still only ChannelReadComplete fires in the ServerHandler fires.

Comment: Client can have two definitions.  One at the Application level where you have a Client that connects to a server.  The other definition is at the socket level where both Client and Server Application has a Client Socket.  I think the Client you posted above is the Client at the Server.  Then you should use TcpListener (not TcpClient) like in following website : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx.  Channel Read will not occur until a Application Client Connects.  Where is your Client Application?

Comment: @jdweng No, this code is the Client Application! Server is runnig and the Client Application is able to connect to the port and send the data. And even server reacts to the request but instead of ChannelRead, only ChannelReadComplete fiers.

Comment: The TCP connection is a stream and end of stream occurs when the stream is closed  TCP splits messages into datagrams with maximum size of datagram is  ~1500 bytes. I think DotNettys ChannelReadCompletes is firing when connection closes (not sure) and occurs when the connection is closed by application or on an error.  Read should fire when each datagram is received.  If the connection is closing immediately after datagram is received you may get only the ChannelReadComplete (good guess).  See following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083868/socket-messages-being-split-by-netty

Comment: @jdweng I am pretty sure the connection is up and alive. The command stm.Read() makes the Client wait for the response from the server and because ChannelRead on the server-side never fires, the connection stays up and running and waiting for response forever. As soon as, I shut down the server, I get this exception in the client: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: Do you think you need an override like on the like I provided?  I'm not that familar with DotNetty.  Maybe adding an end character like a return will force a read to occur.  I think I would first try to send a long message > 1500 bytes and see if you get any reads.  This will give us an indication if the read occurs only when you get a full datagram.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong in the Client Application. I just needed to remove the line below in DotNetty ServerBootstrap configuration (mentioned in their default example).

```
pipeline.AddLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(ushort.MaxValue, 0, 2, 0, 2));
```

Thanks to complete lack of documentation!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I think I found what is the real problem: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

DotNetty is Big-Endian by default, whether BitConverter depends on your platform architecture, so it's quite probable that you are sending Little-Endian message lengths and your LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder is getting stuck (because is still waiting for data to ready). For example, I had a message length of 84 bytes. I sent the length as Little-Endian, which ended as a

> byte[] {84, 0}

However, when converting it from Big-Endian encoding, it ended up as a message length of 21504. Not suprisingly, the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder was getting stuck, waiting for the (21504-84) bytes of data left.

When encoding using Big-Endian:

> byte[] {0, 84}

The length calculated was correct: 84. This time, the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder founds exactly the size it expects and continues execution, delegating to the ChannelHandlerAdapter with exactly the expected 84 bytes of data (86 minus the 2 bytes for length).

I reckon your code works after removing that line because it no longer expects any frames than the actual data, so it reads everything and delegates to the ChannelHandlerAdapter. Unfortunately, this way you will need to handle these first two length bytes by yourself, which is something that you should let Netty solve for you.

You can solve this problem using two approaches:

- Configure DotNetty to use Little-Endian
- Send Big-Endian message lengths

I solved it by using the second approach. Be sure to check whether your platform is using Little or Big endian before converting (it may not be needed at all if you make the assumption in your client platform):

```
var messageLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)messagePayload.Length);

if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    messageLength = messageLength.Reverse().ToArray();
}
```

As you pointed out, DotNetty documentation is lacking, so I don't know how you can configure it to use Little-Endian, but anyway you would need to make the conversion on the client part, so I think the second approach is the best.